# Convergence zêta function for a curve over a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, number-theory, analysis

First of all, some notation : we are considering $F_q$ a finite field, C a curve over $F_q$, and $A_d(C)$ the set of the divisors over C of degree equal to $d$.
I encounter some trouble when trying to prove that the function zêta given by, for $s \in \mathbb{C}$ :
$$\sum_{d \geq 0} A_d(C) q^{-sd}$$ converge for $Re(s) > 1$.

I know that one can prove that there is a $c>0$ such that for all $n$ : $C(F_{q^n}) <= cq^n$, and also the formula given by : $C(F_{q^n}) = \sum_{d | n} d \times |\{v \; $place of $C$ such that $deg(v) =d\}|$

(a place of $C$ is an orbit by the action of $Gal(\overline{F_q}/F_q)$ and its degree its cardinality).

But I dont succeed to uniformly bound $A_d(C) $ to conclure, maybe there is an other way to don't but I dont find out how...

Someone could help me ?

Thank you !

Comment: It is the divisors $\ge 0$ not all divisors. $$\zeta_C(s)=\sum_{D\ge 0} |D|^{-s}=\prod_v \frac1{1-|v|^{-s}}=\prod_n  \frac1{(1-q^{-sn})^{f_n }}=\exp(\sum_n f_n (q^{-sn}+O(q^{-2sn})))$$ where $f_n$ is the number of places with residue field $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$. Then $n f_n$ is the number of points $\in C(\Bbb{F}_{q^n})$ but not on the smaller fields, thus $C(\Bbb{F}_{q^n})=\sum_{d |n} d f_d$.